# Why are scipy and librosa different for reading wav file?

Tags: python, scipy, wav, wave, librosa

So I'm trying to get the samples from a wave file and I noticed that it's a different value depending on whether I use scipy or librosa.

```
sampleFloats, fs = librosa.load('hi.wav', sr=48000)
print('{0:.15f}'.format(sampleFloats[len(sampleFloats)-1]))

from scipy.io.wavfile import read as wavread
# from python_speech_features import mfcc

[samplerate, x] = wavread('hi.wav') # x is a numpy array of integer, representing the samples 

# scale to -1.0 -- 1.0
if x.dtype == 'int16':
    nb_bits = 16 # -> 16-bit wav files
elif x.dtype == 'int32':
    nb_bits = 32 # -> 32-bit wav files
max_nb_bit = float(2 ** (nb_bits - 1))
samples = x / (max_nb_bit + 1.0) # samples is a numpy array of float representing the samples 

print(samples[len(samples)-1])
```

The print statements read:

```
0.001251220703125
0.001274064182641886
```

The sample rate for the file is 48000.

Why might they be different? Is librosa using a different normalization?

Comment: what do the printed numbers represent?

Comment: They represent the value of the last sample.

Comment: FYI (Python tip): `sampleFloats[len(sampleFloats)-1]` can be simplified to `sampleFloats[-1]`

Comment: Why do you divide by `max_nb_bit + 1.0`?  I suspect that should be `max_nb_bit - 1`.

Comment: What happens if you use `sr=None` in the call to `librosa.load()`?

Comment: Thanks for the python tip Warren. The normalization code I found elsewhere, but the values match up exactly right with samples when I grab them with iOS audio framework code, so I’m fairly confident that part is working well. If you put None into the load() it uses a default sampling of 44100 which turns out to be incorrect as well. That’s expected since the sampling is at 48000

Comment: My understanding of librosa is that when you specify the sample rate, the code resamples the data in the file.  If you use `sr=None` and get a sample rate of 44100 with librosa, then that is the same sample rate that the scipy reader will see (check: what is `samplerate` in the python code?).  When you give librosa the argument `sr=48000`, it will resample the signal from 44100 to 48000 and return the resampled signal.  So librosa is doing more preprocessing than the scipy code, and the signals that you are comparing (librosa output and scipy output) are not sampled at the same rate.

Comment: Good call. So you're right that sr=None returns the sample rate 48000, so I didn't need to specify it. However, even when using sr=None, the values remain different, even though the sample rate is the same for the two of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a type mismatch.
It is often useful to print not only the value, but also its type. In this case, because of the way the normalisation is done, type of `samples` values is `float64`, while `librosa` returns `float32`.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42544738/8799210) can help to figure out how to normalise (also, as pointed above, it is indeed `max_nb_bit - 1`, not `+`)